# ThreeJs Object look at mouse with ease

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I'm trying to make an object keep looking at the mouse in a natural-ish way. So far, i've managed to

- make the object look at the mouse at all times
- add an easing to make
  in more natural

The problem is now that the object doesn't follow the same path as the mouse but always takes the last position to ease to.

I'm not sure how to approach this.

```
// create object and add to scene
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
const origin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 75);
sphere.position.x = 0;
sphere.position.z = 0;
sphere.lookAt(origin);
scene.add( sphere );

window.addEventListener("mousemove", onmousemove, false);

var plane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), 0);
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var intersectPoint = new THREE.Vector3();

function onmousemove(event) {
  var startRotation = sphere.quaternion.clone();

  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, intersectPoint);
  intersectPoint.z = 75; // so that the object is still always facing the camera which has a position.z of 75 too
  sphere.lookAt(intersectPoint);
  var endRotation = sphere.quaternion.clone();
  sphere.quaternion.copy( startRotation );
  createjs.Tween.get(sphere.quaternion).to(endRotation, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowOut(2.2));


  marker.position.copy(intersectPoint);
}
```

So the goal is now to find a way to make the object follow the mouse, but not only the last position, its whole path. Any ideas?

Comment: Some inspiration by Karim Maaloul: https://codepen.io/Yakudoo/full/YXxmYR/ ... I would avoid calling `Tween()` every time the mouse moves. Just call `lookAt()`.

Comment: @WestLangley What a cool example, thank you. That is what I did initially but then the rotation was changing in a linear way, i would like to object to rotate with some easing and delay. But maybe i'm still missing something

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make an object look at the mouse with delayed easing by using a pattern like so:

```
var target = new THREE.Vector3();

var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

...

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

    mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
    mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    target.x += ( mouseX - target.x ) * .02;
    target.y += ( - mouseY - target.y ) * .02;
    target.z = camera.position.z; // assuming the camera is located at ( 0, 0, z );

    object.lookAt( target );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

three.js r.131

Comment: it does work perfectly but I'm not sure I understand why. Is it the multiplication in the animate function ?

Comment: Yes. `target` is updated every frame as a function of itself. It's called a feedback-loop.

Comment: Can you explain what about the math causes the easing ?