# 3d model follow mousecursor three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, mouseevent, 3d-model

I recently discovered the `three.js` library and it's been several days that I'm experimenting with it. I would like to add a mouse event to the project, practically the exact same thing as this example, the head of the skull that follows the cursor, only I would like to use only my JSON 3D model (while in the example there are also the model's eyes and the jaw animation to simulate the bite)

This is the link to the example:
https://codepen.io/interaktiv-ca/pen/XayZPx

I tried several times, with this example, to realize it in my project but with an always negative result.

My basic setup is as follows:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera ( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );

camera.position.z = 15;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild ( renderer.domElement );

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls ( camera, renderer.domElement );

var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load("/model/skull.json",function ( obj ) {
    var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject ( obj );
    var center = new THREE.Vector3();
    box.getCenter( center );
    obj.position.sub ( center );
    obj.rotation.y = Math.PI;
    scene.add ( obj );
});

var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

animate();
```

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887057/threejs-object-look-at-mouse-with-ease will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You must define raycaster for know where new positio of your object. You can using my sample code bewlow

```
onMouseMove(event) {
    const that = this;
    const mouse = this.mouse;
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, this.camera);
    const objectListSelect = [];
    objectListSelect.push(this.plane); // your object will moving around this plane
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objectListSelect);
   const item = intersects[i];
     yourobject.position.copy(item.point);

  }
```